# How to toggle contenteditable element true or false in Angular 2

Tags: angular, contenteditable

toggle contenteditable element to true with button call to edit element text and on blur toggle contenteditable element to false when done editing!

how to set contenteditable to false in the class!

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `

    <h2 #el contenteditable="false" (blur)="text=el.textContent">
       This Content is Editable
    </h2>

    <button (click)="toggleContenteditable()">Edit Text Content</button>

    <hr/>
    <p> Text Obj: {{text}}</p>
  `
})
export class App {

  text : string;
  contenteditable:bool = false;

  toggleContenteditable(){
    this.contenteditable = !this.contenteditable;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should use property binding with `attr.` prefix before `contenteditable` and then pass `contenteditable` variable in there. This would help you to perform toggle effect on `contenteditable` via `toggleContenteditable` method.

```
<h2 #el [attr.contenteditable]="contenteditable" (blur)="text=el.textContent">
```

Also change `toggleContenteditable` function to below.

```
toggleContenteditable(){
    this.contenteditable = !this.contenteditable; //`this.` was missing in later assignment
}
```

[**Plunker Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/0xzKwh8JNtijpC2wv9Fw?p=preview)

Comment: Is there a way to validate the input on a td just like required on input fields ?

Comment: This solution did work. But just to mention this because some of my friends asked me, you cannot use [contenteditable] with div element. Only use [attr.contenteditable] or it will give you an error - `Can't bind to 'contenteditable' since it isn't a known property of 'div'`

Comment: @ChetanOswal It will work with a div (I'm using it with one right now), but I've noticed that  the error is usually due to syntax errors on the div.